# Multiply each column in matrix by column in vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

```
sampleInput =

    2.1053   -4.8512    4.6223    0.9665    1.0000


hiddenWeights =

   -0.6342   -0.2089    0.4533   -0.6182   -0.3663
   -0.9465   -1.0770   -0.2668    0.7077   -1.1656
    0.0936   -0.2853   -0.1408    0.6193   -0.5481
    1.4253    0.3770   -0.6710    0.1069    0.0310
```

I want the result to be hiddenWeights, with each column being equal to the previous column * 2.1053. So the first column of hiddenWeights would be:

```
2.1053 * -0.6342
2.1053 * -0.9464
etc.
```

Comment: So did what I suggest help?

Comment: Hi, so did any of our answers help?  [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
out = bsxfun(@times, hiddenWeights, sampleInput);
```

Here, `sampleInput` will duplicate its row by as many times as there are rows in `hiddenWeights` and will undergo an element-wise multiplication with that new matrix with `hiddenWeights`.  The result will be each column of `hiddenWeights` will multiply with the corresponding column in `sampleInput`, and will be what you desire.

Comment: I was going to ask OP what they meant but this kinda explains it;)

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to transform `sampleInput` into a diagonal matrix and apply matrix multiplication:

```
result = hiddenWeights*diag(sampleInput);
```